# What does the icon with a purple square with a "V" mean in IntelliJ-Idea?

Tags: user-interface, intellij-idea, kotlin, icons

[image: Picture Showing Icon]

As shown in the picture, what does the icon with a purple square with a "V" mean in IntelliJ-Idea?

I've looked in the [Icon Reference page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html) for JetBrains but could not find the icon.

Edit: 
[image: different color]

The image above shows that a `val` is a yellow rectangle with a V. This Icon in question is purple.

Comment: I imagine it stands for `val`

Comment: The same Icon is used for `javaClass`, `indices` and `lastIndex`.

Comment: Aren't them all `val`s?

Comment: I added another picture explaining that they are probably different and not `val` because `phrase` is a `val` and has a different color. In the Icon Reference page, the only symbols with a V are in circles and are colored yellow. I might be out of my mind though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`field_value` according to the KotlinIcons list in here https://jetbrains.github.io/ui/resources/icons_list/. here is the screengrab:

[image]

It's for accessing `val` values, whereas a purple circle with the `V` symbol is for accessing `var` values. To understand this, try this simple example:

```
data class Person(val name: String, var age: Int = 1)

fun main() {
    val p = Person("Me")
    p.name // try this and you’ll see a purple square with a “v” sign
    p.age  // this will show you a purple circle with a “v” sign
}
```